# Weird Phantom Error

Tags: anchor, phantom, transaction

[image: enter image description hereasdasd]

Phantom gives this error when I tried to sign my transactions but the weird thing is I have exactly the same solana program and tx structure for different websites and it works with no problem is it something related to domain dns settings or etc.
I haven't seen something like this before.
What is wrong here?

Comment: It's difficult to say with no context of the transaction or program you're invoking. Could you provide more detail?

Comment: What domain is this tx originating from?